Create a custom extension using tiptap
I am currently using (tiptap as for my app's editor. I want to ask is there a way to build a blockquote always have author's tag (this is a custom tag) at the last line of it.
p/s: I am currently using pure Javascript with tiptap version 2.2.2. I have already tried the latest version but it kept getting error so I decided to choose 2.2.2 instead. If anyone knows the answer, I really appreciate!
For example if we click a blockquote button, the HTML will change from:
<p>This is a quote</p>
<p>This is a quote</p>
<p>This is a quote</p>

expecting output:
<blockquote>
     <p>This is a quote</>
     <p>This is a quote</p>
     <p>This is a quote</p>
     <author>Please type the author</author>
</blockquote>

or
from:
<p>
      <br class="ProseMirror-trailingBreak">
</p>

expecting output:
<blockquote>
     <p>
          <br class="ProseMirror-trailingBreak">
     </p>
     <author>Please type the author</author>
</blockquote>

All of the parts in blockquote also can be edited.

The question is a bit vague, and I'm not sure how familiar you are with Tiptap and it's extension system, but I'd start from here https://tiptap.dev/docs/editor/extensions/custom-extensions
You'll probably have to use Node views https://tiptap.dev/docs/editor/extensions/custom-extensions/node-views
